# Powers of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that $z^n = r^n e^{in\theta}$ where z is complex and i is imaginary.

My question is this: what is meant by 'find all values of the following powers: $1^{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

So $z = 1^{\sqrt{2}}$, but we can't just say $z = 1$ and $n = \sqrt2$. However, the solution I am looking at does just that, but not explicitly. It says, $1^\sqrt2 = e^{\sqrt{2} \log(1)}$ from the formula  $z^n = e^{n\log(z)}$.

Can anyone explain?

---

I cannot delete my question, but I have resolved it on my own. It's 2am.

Comment: Just write an answer for yourself, so people with the same problem can understand it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formula $z^a=\mathrm e^{a\log z}$, $\log$ denotes the *complex* logarithm, which is defined only modulo $2\mathrm i\pi$.

Here $\,\log 1\equiv 0 \mod 2\mathrm i\pi$, hence $1^\sqrt 2=\mathrm e^{2\sqrt 2\mathrm i\pi}=\cos(2\sqrt 2\pi)+\mathrm i\sin(2\sqrt 2\pi)$.

Comment: Do you mean $z^a$. If so, then I agree.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing the typo. Fixed now.